# What is the behaviour of this function? (Power of two)

Tags: c

I have next function:

```
static inline int nextPowerOfTwo(int n) {
    n--;

    n = n >>  1 | n;
    n = n >>  2 | n;
    n = n >>  4 | n;
    n = n >>  8 | n;
    n = n >> 16 | n;
    //  n = n >> 32 | n;    //  For 64-bit ints

    return ++n;
}
```

But I do not know which is his behavior (the function output -his functionality-)

I do not know neither what is the behavior of each line (n value after each line).

Can someone explain me it?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You can run the code and see what it does.  Please post the output that you are seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code comes from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2)

> #### Round up to the next highest power of 2
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // compute the next highest power of 2 of 32-bit v
>
> v--;
> v |= v >> 1;
> v |= v >> 2;
> v |= v >> 4;
> v |= v >> 8;
> v |= v >> 16;
> v++;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> It works by copying the highest set bit to all of the lower
>   bits, and then adding one, which results in carries that set all of
>   the lower bits to 0 and one bit beyond the highest set bit to 1. If
>   the original number was a power of 2, then the decrement will reduce
>   it to one less, so that we round up to the same original value.

The obvious versions for 16, 32 and 64 bit:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t round_u16_to_pow2(uint16_t v)
{
    v--;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v++;
    return v;
}

uint32_t round_u32_to_pow2(uint32_t v)
{
    v--;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v++;
    return v;
}

uint64_t round_u64_to_pow2(uint64_t v)
{
    v--;
    v |= v >> 1;
    v |= v >> 2;
    v |= v >> 4;
    v |= v >> 8;
    v |= v >> 16;
    v |= v >> 32;
    v++;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: It does assume a 32-bit `unsigned` type so will have undefined behaviour for a 16-bit type and will not give the required result for (say) a 64-bit type.

Comment: @Peter Oh, And how could I contemplate 16-bit int ?

Comment: And another question, if it is not so much trouble. Maximum value returned is 2048, why? How could I establish maximum on 1024? (without: `return ( (n <= 1023) ? ++n : 1024 ) `, so proccess should stop when `n == 1023` and then, `return ++n`)

Comment: @JuMoGar Um, no, the maximum returned is not 2048.

Comment: Yes, It was my fault, a bad `printf`.... Sorry. And exist any way of maximum returned must be 1024 changing bits operations? There isn't, right?

Comment: @JuMoGar Given the code we're talking about I don't see a way. There is no loop one could break.